# How do I rotate a grid of edges on a cube without changing the shape of the cube?

Tags: mesh

I start with a cube, and then subdivide the front face a bunch to create a grid.[image]

My goal is to rotate the grid of edges 45 degrees.  So I tried shearing them and I get this...
[image]

Which changes the shape of the cube.  So then I tried rotating them and I get this...
[image]

So how do I rotate a grid of edges on a cube without changing the shape of the cube?  The only way I can think to do it is using the knife tool which would be very time consuming and inacurate.  Can I rotate edge loops before placing them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply un-subdivide it an odd number of times.

[image: unsub]

In edit mode, *Un-Subdivide* command is under Edge menu.

If this doesn't work for specific geometry, you can do *Faces > Poke* on selection, then select vertical/horizontal lines (e.g. by selecting verts by number of connecting edges), then dissolve the edges.

Comment: Thank you both for your answers.  @chedap  I tried doing your second method locally and the poke faces worked to get the edges at 45 degrees just fine.  The problem I'm now having is selecting the verticle and horizontal edge loops to delete them.  It will only let me select each edge one at a time.  How do I do this?

Comment: I shouldn't have used the word "locally", it's misleading. You can use unsubdivide in edit mode too. Poke is for unusual cases. You won't be able to select loops because of triangles, which is why I said you'd have to go by "Select Similar". [Here's a demo.](https://i.imgur.com/ykn6467.mp4)

Comment: I used the first unsubdivide method you showed in the video and it worked great.  Much thanks for the video.  I consider myself still a novice in 3D modelling so spelling it out helps a lot.

Answer (score 0):

A Boolean modifier would work.

Subdivide a cube as you did originally and rotate it 45 degrees to get the grid pattern you want. Add another smaller cube just inside it so that it intersect with an entire face completely, like so:

[image: subdivided cube]

With the smaller cube selected, add a Boolean modifier, with Intersect selected, and set the object to the larger grid cube you had subdivided [image: Boolean modifier]

Then apply the modifier:
[image: Apply modifier]

Now you can delete the cube you had subdivided, and the smaller cube will have the grid pattern:

[image: cube with grid pattern rotated 45 degrees]